# Run only single gitlab-ci job on automated release commit which also creates a tag

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I asked the following also at https://forum.gitlab.com/t/run-only-single-job-on-automated-release-commit-which-also-creates-a-tag/98816 but got no reply so far...

#### starting point

I use semantic-release for automated releasing. When a release is created I have a commit message like

```
chore(release): \d+.\d+.\d+
```

and a tag `d\+.\d+.\d+` created.

I have following `gitlab-ci.yml` for testing

```yaml
---
stages:
  - debug
  - test
  - release
  - deploy

debugging:
  stage: debug
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - echo "GitLab CI/CD | Print all environment variables"
    - env | sort

test1:
  stage: test
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - echo "run tests"

semantic-release:
  stage: release
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - echo "run semantic release"

deploy-pages:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - echo "deploy pages"
```

I want to achieve the following:

1. run the `deploy-pages` job only once for an automated release commit
2. run the `test1` and `semantic-release` jobs only for non automated release commits, i.e. regular commits created by actual humans.

**What is the best way to do that?**

---

#### My current status

I for my automatic releases two pipelines are triggered, one tag pipeline and one regular commit pipeline.

I already achieved 1. by adding

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
    - when: never
```

to the job `deploy-pages`.

Solving 2. is where my problem actually is.

In my latest attempts I try to use regex matching against `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`, i.e. a `rules` block for `test1` and `sematic-release` jobs like

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $RELEASE_COMMIT_MSG_PATTERN
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```

where I tried following `$RELEASE_COMMIT_MSG_PATTERN` s in a global `variables:` block

```
RELEASE_COMMIT_MSG_PATTERN: "/^chore(release): [[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+$/"
RELEASE_COMMIT_MSG_PATTERN: "/^chore(release): \\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$/"
RELEASE_COMMIT_MSG_PATTERN: "/^chore(release): .*"
RELEASE_COMMIT_MSG_PATTERN: "/^chore(release):/"
```

But the regex match seems not to work.
**In addition to my question above: Is there a way to test the regex match?**
I am thinking of a tool like https://regex101.com/ but for gitlab regex (based on Re2 which according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern is what is used in Gitlab).

Comment: As for regex testing, I think using regex101.com with PCRE2 works. I think perhaps you meant to escape the first set of capture group parenthesis to be literals? Unless you actually start the commit message pattern like `chorerelease` with no space. Same with the `.` characters; they should be escaped if you want them to be interpreted as literal decimals. In your later examples, the escapes don't seem correct. Check the tokens in regex101. I think you want something like `chore\(release\): \d+\.\d+\.\d+` to match `chore(release): 1.2.3`. Giving examples of messages may help getting an answer.

Comment: @sytech yes indeed, you are right. but if I use the regex you mentioned (which should work according to regex101 PCRE2. The pipeline editor complains about `Invalid escape sequence \(YAML(0)` and if I use `"/^chore\\(release\\): \\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$/"` it does not work as expected.

Comment: I see. You're escaping for the YAML syntax in the double quoted string, which looks correct. Try just dropping the `^` and `$` characters from the pattern and see if it works how you expect.

Comment: @sytech apparently this worked. I am however confused as to why the start / end mark does not work. Any ideas? In any case, do you want to put this into an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your commit message contents are, but I think the markers would work if you used `$CI_COMMIT_TITLE` instead.

Comment: @sytech, I can confirm that `$CI_COMMIT_TITLE` works just fine with the markers!